# Using Shopify Metafields in Product Block/Section

Tags: shopify, themes

I'm using Porto Shopify theme 4.0.3, and I'm attempting to include Metafields in my Default Page template for dynamic use when a product is displayed. We sell Guitars and Musical Instruments, so we have Metafields like 'Top Material' 'Pickup Configuration' 'String Type', etc. I'd like these to be displayed in a tab called 'Specs'. With Porto I can do a 'Tab Custom HTML' under 'Product Page' (screenshots below), but trying to include the metafields in the Custom HTML box returns the error `Setting 'code' can't include Liquid syntax ('{{', '}}', '{%' or '%}') without valid dynamic sources.`

Does anyone know if I have other options to include metafields on the Product Page of Porto 4.0.3? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

'Html content' requires html. You've inputted liquid here. I think what you're looking for is a liquid input type for your block. I'm not sure if your theme has a section for 'Tab Custom Liquid', but you could always add one to your theme code if needed. Some themes have the section listed as 'Custom Liquid'.